# Visual C# - Modify Headers Webkit Browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webkit

I am building a project using the WebKit Browser. Is there any way I can change the headers WebKit sends in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetHeader` or `AddHeader` methods

```
    var wbkit = new WebKit.WebKitBrowser();
    var header = new WebKit.Header("User-Agent", "value");
    wbkit.SetHeader(header, "value");
    //wbkit.AddHeader(header);
```